# How would I make a playsound follow another player and hear it coming from them?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm on Minecraft Bedrock and I was wondering if there's a way to make a sound follow another player and hear the sound coming from them. It's for a map I was building.

Comment: It's probably not possible like that, at least I know it's impossible in MCJava. A sound there always has exactly one location. But you could split it up into many shorter sounds and play them with the right timing. (Not posting an answer, because I don't know if it's true for MCBE.)

Comment: @FabianRöling yes, unfortunately that is also the case in Bedrock. They have been thinking about improving the sound system, but at this time has the same restrictions as Java - once a sound starts playing, its location cannot be changed.

Comment: @Plagiatus Then you can answer that.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, while bedrock has a better music system for long background music than java, it's not possible to have moving sounds at this time (1.19.70).

There are two types of sounds in the game:

- location based sounds
- UI sounds

The former will play from a fixed location in the world - unchangeable once started. The player will hear them as a directional sound.
The later are independent of location and will play to the player in stereo, non-directional.

So if you want a longer sound to move with the player, you'll need to cut it into smaller chunks and play them one after the other, updating the sound position with the source.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible if you want to play a short sound like a block breaking or a mob noise. [image: this is for a zombie named jimmy]
It says "jimmy" because that's what I named a zombie but you should do the mobs' name where the `@e` is.
Also, [here](https://www.digminecraft.com/lists/sound_list_pe.php) is the sound effects you can use.

Comment: ...but that's not what he was asking; he was asking if you could play a sound that *follows* the player, as in a sense of them walking around and still hearing it.